# java.lang.NullPointerException at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm creating Android launcher that has multiple tabs with swipe gestures to get from one fragment to the other all of my screens are working just fine except for the ShelfViewActivity (even though it says activity is a fragment) everything works fine but when i scroll to ShelfViewActivity the launcher crashes. I have the logcat here as well as the class. the error is on line 35 I think.... I have commented where line 35 is.I don't know what i'm doing wrong i'm still learning so please don't judge

LogCat:

```
11-12 05:30:55.337: E/AndroidRuntime(3889): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 05:30:55.337: E/AndroidRuntime(3889): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-12 05:30:55.337: E/AndroidRuntime(3889):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
11-12 05:30:55.337: E/AndroidRuntime(3889):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
11-12 05:30:55.337: E/AndroidRuntime(3889):     at com.d4a.tobias.ShelfViewActivity$VerticalAdapter.<init>(ShelfViewActivity.java:51)
11-12 05:30:55.337: E/AndroidRuntime(3889):     at com.d4a.tobias.ShelfViewActivity.<init>(ShelfViewActivity.java:35)
11-12 05:30:55.337: E/AndroidRuntime(3889):     at it.gmariotti.android.examples.googleaccount.MainFrag$MyAdapter.getItem(MainFrag.java:80)
11-12 05:30:55.337: E/AndroidRuntime(3889):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:95)
```

ShelfViewActivity.java

```
package com.d4a.tobias;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ShelfViewActivity extends ListFragment {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private VerticalAdapter verListAdapter;

    @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    }   

        /*
         * Calling Library & BookItem classes for create list of groups
         *  groupbyArrayBookItem return back array of array of items
         */
        Library lb = new Library();{
        for (BookItem item : BookItem.ALL_BOOKS) {
            lb.addBookItem(item);
        }
        ArrayList<ArrayList<BookItem>> groupList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<BookItem>>();
        groupList = lb.groupbyArrayBookItem(Library.AUTHOR);

        verListAdapter = new VerticalAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.bookrow, groupList);  //line 35
        setListAdapter(verListAdapter);

        verListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /**
     * This class add a list of ArrayList to ListView that it include multi
     * items as bookItem.
     */
    private class VerticalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<BookItem>> {

        private int resource;

        public VerticalAdapter(Context _context, int _ResourceId,
                ArrayList<ArrayList<BookItem>> _items) {
            super(_context, _ResourceId, _items);
            this.resource = _ResourceId;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View rowView;

            if (convertView == null) {
                rowView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(resource,
                        null);
            } else {
                rowView = convertView;
            }

            HorizontalListView hListView = (HorizontalListView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.subListview);
            HorizontalAdapter horListAdapter = new HorizontalAdapter(
                    getContext(), R.layout.item, getItem(position));
            hListView.setAdapter(horListAdapter);

            return rowView;
        }
    }

    /*
     * This class add some items to Horizontal ListView this ListView include
     * several bookItem.
     */
    private class HorizontalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BookItem> {

        private int resource;

        public HorizontalAdapter(Context _context, int _textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<BookItem> _items) {
            super(_context, _textViewResourceId, _items);
            this.resource = _textViewResourceId;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View retval = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    this.resource, null);

            TextView topText = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView bottomText = (TextView) retval
                    .findViewById(R.id.author);

            topText.setText(getItem(position).getAuthor());
            bottomText.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());

            return retval;
        }
    }
}
```

any help would be amazing

Thanks way in advance!

Comment: I'm going out on a limb, and without digging into the code, I can't really see 'setContentView' anywhere. Maybe you're using some different approach, but that should be one of the first things you need to call. I may be wrong, havent gone through the whole code.

Comment: may be you are getting null value. Debug the code

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
 @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
}   

    /*
     * Calling Library & BookItem classes for create list of groups
     *  groupbyArrayBookItem return back array of array of items
     */
    Library lb = new Library();{
    for (BookItem item : BookItem.ALL_BOOKS) {
        lb.addBookItem(item);
    }
    ArrayList<ArrayList<BookItem>> groupList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<BookItem>>();
    groupList = lb.groupbyArrayBookItem(Library.AUTHOR);

    verListAdapter = new VerticalAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.bookrow, groupList);  //line 35
    setListAdapter(verListAdapter);

    verListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

To this:

```
@Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false); 

    /*
     * Calling Library & BookItem classes for create list of groups
     *  groupbyArrayBookItem return back array of array of items
     */
    Library lb = new Library();{
    for (BookItem item : BookItem.ALL_BOOKS) {
        lb.addBookItem(item);
    }
    ArrayList<ArrayList<BookItem>> groupList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<BookItem>>();
    groupList = lb.groupbyArrayBookItem(Library.AUTHOR);

    verListAdapter = new VerticalAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.bookrow, groupList);  //line 35
    setListAdapter(verListAdapter);

    verListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: i'm getting this error: rootView cannot be resolved to a 
 variable what am I doing wrong??